# Call to member function num_rows() on non object using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am stuck at this silly problem, for quite a few times and i know i might have done some silly mistake, basically i have a controller which calls a model function and returns data and then assign it in an array, but i keep getting call to member function num_rows on non object member error,

My controller function is:

```
public function registerNewLease()
{
    $this->load->model('AnnualBudget');
    $alreadyExist = $this->AnnualBudget->checkAlreadyExist($client_block_ID);
    if ($alreadyExist == FALSE) 
    {
      // code if nothing found
    } else 
    {
     for ($i=0; $i < $alreadyExist->num_rows(); $i++) 
     { 
       $row = $alreadyExist->row($i);
       $FY_budget_ID[$i] = $row->FY_budget_ID;
     }
    }
}

My model is :

public function checkAlreadyExist($client_block_ID)
{
    $this->db->select('FY_budget_ID');
    $this->db->where('client_block_ID', $client_block_ID);
    $query = $this->db->get('fy_budget');
    if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) 
    {
        return $query;
    } else 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

The error is in the else part where num_rows function is called...

Comment: Then probably $this->db->get() is returning `false` instead of an object. place a `var_dump($this->db->last_query())` after your `$this->db->get()` and check the SQL statement

Comment: And I'm not sure if `$this->db->get()` returns an Object anyway

Comment: I agree with Patrick.  This is a common situation to be in if the results of queries are not checked for success.

Comment: if it was returning FALSE then, the control should goto the true part of return statement instead of going to the else part.. it is returning something, and using var_dump i found bool(true), which i did not return...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function checkAlreadyExist($client_block_ID)
{
    $data   = array();
    $this->db->select('FY_budget_ID');
    $this->db->where('client_block_ID', $client_block_ID);
    $data   = $this->db->get('fy_budget')->result_array();
    return $data;
}

public function registerNewLease()
{
    $this->load->model('AnnualBudget');
    $FY_budget_ID = array();
    $alreadyExist = $this->AnnualBudget->checkAlreadyExist($client_block_ID);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    /*if( isset( $alreadyExist ) && count( $alreadyExist ) > 0 ){
        foreach ( $alreadyExist as $key => $each ) 
        { 
            $FY_budget_ID[$key] = $each['FY_budget_ID'];
        }    
    }*/
    echo "<pre>";print_r( $alreadyExist );
}
```

Comment: This will `return` an empty array, because you're initializing `$data` but you never fill anything into it :P

Comment: Yes, I know that, and thats always a good option to initialize an array and return it instead of what to OP is doing I think. Doing this you will not face any such error as in this the OP is facing. You will always be sure of what the output might be. @PatrickManser

Comment: See @RoyalBg's answer. You initialize it, never fill anything into it and then you return it empty.

Comment: My bad, `$query` should be `$data`, Now, its okay. :P @PatrickManser

Comment: @blogger :  try this and let me know.

Comment: sorry my bad, i should not have commented. Deleted the comment anyways. BUT; now the error is wrong argument supplied to foreach()

Comment: as i mentioned now the error is:wrong argument supplied to foreach()

Comment: sorry was on break, now the error is:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(); and below that Array (
)

Answer (score 0):

if you get stucked in `for` loop, try to use `foreach`. It is my updated answer :

```
public function registerNewLease()
{
        $this->load->model('AnnualBudget');
        $alreadyExist = $this->AnnualBudget->checkAlreadyExist($client_block_ID);
        if ($alreadyExist != NULL){
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($alreadyExist->result_array() as $row){
            $i++;
            $FY_budget_ID[$i] = $row['FY_budget_ID'];
            }
        }
        else{
    //no result here
         echo "no result";
        }
}
```

and the model:

```
function checkAlreadyExist($client_block_ID)
{
     return $this->db->get_where('fy_budget','client_block_ID' => $client_block_ID);
}
```

Comment: if it was returning FALSE then, the control should goto the true part of return statement instead of going to the else part.. it is returning something, and using var_dump i found bool(true), which i did not return...

Comment: change `result()` with `result_array()`. but you have to change `$row->FY_budget_ID` to `$row['FY_budget_ID']` because it will be an array. i'm sorry about that :D

Comment: what about replace `    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) 
    {
        return FALSE;
    } else 
    {
        return $query;
    }` in model, i think it doesn't needed here. just `return $this->db->get_where('fy_budget','client_block_ID' => $client_block_ID);`. i will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

use following

```
public function registerNewLease()
{
    $this->load->model('AnnualBudget');
    $alreadyExist = $this->AnnualBudget->checkAlreadyExist($client_block_ID);
    if ($alreadyExist == FALSE) 
    {
      // code if nothing found
    } else 
    {
     for ($i=0; $i < $this->db->count_all_results(); $i++) 
     { 
       $row = $alreadyExist->row($i);
       $FY_budget_ID[$i] = $row->FY_budget_ID;
     }
    }
}

My model is :

public function checkAlreadyExist($client_block_ID)
{
    $this->db->select('FY_budget_ID');
    $this->db->where('client_block_ID', $client_block_ID);
    $query = $this->db->get('fy_budget');
    if ($this->db->count_all_results() >= 1) 
    {
        return $query;
    } else 
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```